# Trouble changing ruby version for sh

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, ruby-2.3

I'm having a little trouble configuring ruby in OSX.

Under bash, all is well, version 2.3.1 is running, my gems are installed in 2.3.1, all hunky dory

But in sh, version 2.3.0 is running. I can't see where that is set, having looked in the profiles.

This is an issue because I'm using an application that opens up a bourne shell to do some work.. and the work involves ruby.

I tried 'rvm use' but I get an "rvm is not a function" message.

typing `~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing via homebrew, after it installs it should show you how to symlink it to the system install.

Comment: It didn't say anything about symlinks, but rvm use seems to have worked now, so it's running the correct version and finding the gem.. but then runs into another problem, which I may have to ask another question about if I can't find the answer on here already